# Converting a string to an NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, formatting, nsdate

How is it possible to convert a string to an `NSDate` on iOS?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

```
NSString *dateStr = @"20100223";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
[dateFormat release];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: found an article that explains all the format values here: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/

Comment: Also note unicode.org's listing: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Do you know why small letter yyyy and dd works and capital letter MM works...?

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to take a look at [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Determine the format of the date string and then use `dateFromString:` to convert the string to an NSDate object.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  
list = [self getYear:date];


- (NSMutableArray *)getYear:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];

    int year = [components year];
    int month = [components month];
    int day = [components day];
    NSLog(@"%d",year);

    NSMutableDictionary *dateDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", day], @"day", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", month], @"month", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", year], @"year", nil];

    return dateDict;
}
```

Comment: return type is NSMutableArray, but your returning NSMutableDictionary why?

Answer (score 3):

My working version in Swift

```
func dateFor(timeStamp: String) -> NSDate
{
    let formater = NSDateFormatter()
    formater.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss:SSS - MMM dd, yyyy"
    return formater.dateFromString(timeStamp)!
}


func timeStampFor(date: NSDate) -> String
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss:SSS - MMM dd, yyyy"

    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [simple approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) even if you have sqlite DB:

```
// NSTimeInterval is basically typedef of double so you can receive it as double also.
NSTimeInterval *current = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; 
[DB addToDB:current];

//retrieve the date from DB
NSDate *retrievedDateItem = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[getDBValueAsDouble]]; //convert it from double (NSTimeInterval) to NSDate
// Set the style
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
// Converted to string
NSString *convertedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:retrievedDateItem];
```

The output for this example:

**Aug 3, 2015, 12:27:50 PM**

Answer (score 1):

```
+(NSDate*)str2date:(NSString*)dateStr{
    if ([dateStr isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
        return (NSDate*)dateStr;
    }

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    return date;
}
```