# create a NSDate from a string

Tags: objective-c, ios, format, nsdate

I have an `NSString` like this: `@"3/15/2012 9:15 PM"` and I would like to convert it to `NSDate`, I have done like this:

```
NSString *str =@"3/15/2012 9:15 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:];

NSLog(@"%@", date);  // date = null
```

Can you help me please, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert string to nsdate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/convert-string-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the following solution

```
NSString *str = @"3/15/2012 9:15 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a";

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

**Edit:**
Sorry, the format should be as follows:

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a";
```

And the time shown will be GMT time. So if you add/subtract the timezone, it would be 9:15 PM.

**Edit: #2**

Use as below. You would get exact time too.

```
NSString *str = @"3/15/2012 9:15 PM";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a";

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

formatter.timeZone = gmt;

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: it's not the same result : NSLog(@"str") =3/13/2012 2:00 PM
 NSLog(@"date") =  2012-01-13 11:00:00 +0000

Comment: Thanks, the date is the same but not the time, i am sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your formatter is wrong. According to the NSDateFormatter documentation it should be "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a". You also probably want to set the locale as stated in the Date Formatting Guideline:

> If you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the
>   locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed
>   format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX, a
>   locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results
>   regardless of both user and system preferences.

Try this:

```
NSString *str = @"3/15/2012 9:15 AM";
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Outputs:

```
2012-03-19 12:37:27.531 Untitled[6554:707] 2012-03-15 08:15:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm - you've gone wrong for a couple of reasons

1. the NSDateFormatter is strict and you have not been.
2. you didn't supply str to dateFromString:

```cpp
NSString* str = @"3/15/2012 9:15 PM";
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:str];


NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: Thanks, but all my strings are like this @"mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm PM/AM", it's a web service who return to me this

Comment: 3 is true , unless he's using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *str =@"3/15/2012 9:15 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSArray *firstSplit = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSDate *dateSelected = [dateformatter dateFromString:[firstSplit objectAtIndex:0]];

    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateSelected2 = [dateformatter dateFromString:[firstSplit objectAtIndex:1]];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateformatter stringFromDate:dateSelected2]);

NSLog(@"%@",[dateformatter stringFromDate:dateSelected]);
```

Comment: whats the problem do you want the time

Comment: [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
 NSDate *dateSelected2 = [dateformatter dateFromString:[firstSplit objectAtIndex:1]];
 NSLog(@"%@",[dateformatter stringFromDate:dateSelected2]);