# set fireDate of UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilocalnotification

I'm using this app
[here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/07/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html)
it works fine with me but I want to insert the fireDate of local notification manually instead of using the datePicker.

```
notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
```

How can I insert date (day, month, year, hours and minutes) manually?

I tried the following

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:10];
[dateComps setMonth:3];
[dateComps setYear:2013];
[dateComps setHour:4];
[dateComps setMinute:45];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

int minutesBefore = 2;
notif.fireDate = [itemDate addTimeInterval:-(minutesBefore*60)];
```

but it not works with me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Create an instance of `NSDate` and use that?

Comment: can you show me how, please? I'm new in this.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can convert directly from a `NSString` to a `NSDate`. Here's an example:

```
NSDateFormatter* myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[myFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate* myDate = [myFormatter dateFromString:@"8/26/2012"];
NSLog(@"%@", myDate);
```

**EDIT**
If you want time too

```
NSString *str =@"3/15/2012 9:15 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[formatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Follow this link for more info [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769190/create-a-nsdate-from-a-string)

And for localNotification just implement this too after fire date

```
UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: I want to set the hours and minutes too.

Comment: it worked with me, I discovered that I forgot to comment this line: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; .. sorry. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: this line will cancel all your previous notifications

Answer (score 0):

How about using `addTimeInterval`?

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = [itemDate addTimeInterval:-(minutesBefore*60)]; 

 //minutesBefore will be type of int and itemDate would be of NSDate type.
```

Update 1:

After searching little I found out `addTimeInterval` is deprecated in iOS 4 and further. Instead you should use `dateByAddingTimeInterval`.

```
 localNotif.fireDate = [itemDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(minutesBefore*60)];
```

*Providing negative value to `dateByAddingTimeInterval` will fire notification minutes **earlier** to the `itemDate`*.

Comment: I posted solution before you made edit. But I suppose [Rajneesh071](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1369972/rajneesh071) has provided perfect solution to your query.