# NSDate returning nil when converting from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to get the time of day from a date string. The following string should return 12:00AM.

2010-08-24 00:00:00 +0000

But using the following code, my NSDate object returns nil when it reaches the log statement. What is the issue here? Thanks!

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"h:mma"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:@"2010-08-24 00:00:00 +0000"];
NSLog(@"DATE: %@", [date description]);
```

Output: DATE: (null)

Comment: Its because the date format(String) your passing doen't match with the date format.... try using the same date format....

Comment: possible duplicate of [create a NSDate from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769190/create-a-nsdate-from-a-string)

Comment: Why doesn't anyone ever consult the documentation??

Comment: @HotLicks ...because they can just get someone on SO to look it up for them.

Comment: You have accepted an incorrect answer.

Comment: @quellish - So why aren't the people providing the answers consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:@"2010-08-24 00:00:00 +0000"];
NSLog(@"DATE: %@", [date description]);
```

Cheers!

Tested on playgorund:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how can I just return the time of day?

Comment: [NSDate date]; // returns today date

Comment: (Convert "2010-01-01 23:42:00 +0000")

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the following procedure to extract time from the date string

1.Get NSDate object in its given format.

2.Set the NSDateFormatter object with the required format.

3.Get the date string in required format.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)
application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    NSString *date = [self convertDate:@"2010-08-24 00:00:00 +0000"
                            fromFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"
                              toFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    NSLog(@"DATE: %@", [date description]);

    return YES;
}


- (NSString *)convertDate:(NSString *)inDateString
             fromFormat:(NSString *)fromFormat
               toFormat:(NSString *)toFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
    NSString *outDateString = nil;
    NSDate *date = nil;

    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:fromFormat];

    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inDateString];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:toFormat];
    outDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    return outDateString;
}
```

Comment: Your date format is incorrect (though not as incorrect as the others).