# Trying to Convert String to Date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert string to nsdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/convert-string-to-nsdate)

The NSString has following value '2012-07-11T15:59:16'

I am unable to determine the correct format for NSDateFomatter.dateFormat property in order to covert it using dateFromString method. I tried 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss' and other similar formats but resultant date is nil.

A link with info about date formatting would be highly appreciated too.

Comment: what is this "T" in the middle?? in this string  '2012-07-11T15:59:16'

Comment: i am wondering too .. It's actually a webservice written in django that is returning date in this format including the 'T'

Comment: @Monolo this is not a duplicate as the other question has answer use NSDateFormatter but this already knows NSDateFormatter

Comment: @Leena - the T is what is used in ISO dates http://dotat.at/tmp/ISO_8601-2004_E.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you should be able to get it to work if you escape the the `T`:

```
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Yes it is, except that the time is now set to `GMT`. The NSDate object removes the timezone information.

Comment: Works perfectly .. It was a debugging mistake .. =) You're Awesome