# Turning NSDate into NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert NSDate to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring)
>   [convert string to nsdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/convert-string-to-nsdate)

Currently I have this code. It's for adding events to the calendar.

```
[...]
event.startDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];
event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:90000];
```

What I need is the code to add to a spesific start date and end date, and that's where NSString comes in handy. But I've had no luck converting it so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer this code :

**NSString to NSDate**

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];
```

**NSDate convert to NSString:**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks! How do I add it to the calendar though? (With regards to the code I previously posted)

Comment: @GThamanTitan : I guess you are already adding to event calendar, what do you want exactly?

Comment: What I meant is what should I write in the event.StartDate code now? (Instead of DateByAddingTimeInterval)

Comment: ok, so you are getting in NSString format and you want to convert it into NSDate, what is format of NSString you are getting, try NSLog it

Comment: I changed the code to event.startDate = [[NSDate date] dateFromString:@"dateString"]; and the app crashes.

Comment: are you familiar with ObjectiveC coding, what is value you are getting in dateString

Comment: check my above NSString to NSDate, just paste same code as it is, and also check if you are getting dateString value in format of dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: I'm a beginner to Objective-C. I set it to dateString because it refers to the date "01-02-2010".

Comment: NSLog dateString and tell me data you are getting there

Comment: This is the error I get: http://imgur.com/q5iD1

Comment: just replace your crash code line with event.startDate = dateFromString;

Comment: Great thanks so much! But now the date is not correct, it adds the event tomorrow, not the date I specified.

Comment: You need to set locale of your calendar event properly, i.e. GMT

Answer (score 0):

convert NSDate to NSString as

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSString *string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an example if you need the format like  “Nov 23, 1937”:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle= NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSString* string= [formatter stringFromDate: date];
```

Check out the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for other styles. If you need another style that hasn't a constant, you can use the date format, in this case it's:

```
formatter.dateFormat= @"MMM dd, yyyy"; // same as medium style
```

But the preferred way is to use the style, use the format only if there isn't a propert style.