# Convert string with ordinal format to date on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a string to an NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/convert-string-to-nsdate)

---

I have date in string and want to convert in NSDate. In string date is:

> "21st June 2012"

How can I convert this in NSDate?

Please concentrate on day "21st" not "21" when you give answer.

Comment: "If you want to end the hunger forever, dont give a fish to hungry man, teach him fishing".. I think this is an English idiom, google for 'convert NSString to NSDate' and read related topics on Apple Docs. Get started [now](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: **11.422** SO questions regarding NSDates so far,see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSDates, and **4745** for Your topic! Still repeating the questions .

Comment: I can't find the way to convert the given date formate "21st June 2012" to NSDate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to an NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/converting-a-string-to-an-nsdate)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. The page you linked does not address parsing a string that uses ordinals (`21st` is an ordinal). Parsing the ordinal is what makes this question hard to answer.

Comment: @robmayoff Not that hard: `if string == "21st June 2012" { return NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1_340_208_000) }`. (OK, I added a better answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter) to change NSString to NSDate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic answer for this kind of questions [available on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/convert-string-to-nsdate), it's to use [NSDateFormatter in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter?language=objc) / [DateFormatter in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter). And the format is following [tr35-19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns) or newer according to [Use Format Strings to Specify Custom Formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).

But to deal with your variation of a date format, here is the Swift answer for your specific requirements:

```
// Your example
let dateString = "21st June 2012"

// Sanitizing input for 2nd, 3rd, 4th
let normalizedDateString = dateString.replacingOccurrences(of: "nd", with: "st").replacingOccurrences(of: "rd", with: "st").replacingOccurrences(of: "th", with: "st")

// Converting string to date object
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.dateFormat = "d'st' MMMM yyyy"
let date = formatter.date(from: normalizedDateString)
```

Same logic in Objective-C.