# Creating AVPlayerLayer prevents releasing AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, retain-cycle, avplayerlayer

If I ever set an AVPlayerLayer, then there will be some retain cycle that will prevent `deinit` from ever being called.

```
import AVFoundation

class MyPlayer: AVPlayer {

    fileprivate(set) lazy var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer = {
        // Create a player layer
        $0.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return $0
    }(AVPlayerLayer(player: self))

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("MyPlayer init")

        _ = playerLayer
    }

    deinit {
        print("MyPlayer deinit")
    }
}
```

Testing with this, only *"MyPlayer init"* will be printed:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    _ = MyPlayer()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Please stop making pointless edits in years old questions! It makes them pop up as new questions. Especially if you’re changing the name of a linked duplicate question that is automatically generated! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600914/change-date-format-ios-objective-c?noredirect=1

Comment: @Fogmeister correcting titles of linked questions seems quite important.

Comment: the title of the linked question was edited ... to put an ‘a’ in link still worked. Except now I went to reopen the question because I thought it was closed in haste. And then was about to answer when I realised it was nearly 5 years old. Sure, resurrect a question if the answer has massively changed. But the link still worked. Nothing significantly changed in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVPlayerLayer` is keeping a strong reference to the player, so you shouldn't keep a strong reference of the playerLayer from the player itself.

#### Solution 1

If you don't plan to remove the sublayer, then the superlayer will keep the reference for you, so you can use `weak`:

```
private weak var _playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer! {
    if let p = _playerLayer {
        return p
    }
    let p: AVPlayerLayer = {
        // Create a player layer
        $0.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return $0
    }(AVPlayerLayer(player: self))
    _playerLayer = p
    return p
}
```

#### Solution 2

If you plan to remove and re-add the sublayer, then you need the strong reference variable to be made in your UIView, UIViewController or some other manager for the playerLayer.

Answer (score 1):

In you code `MyPlayer` keep reference to the `playerLayer` property. And `playerLayer` property keep reference to the `MyPlayer`. That's make retain cycle.

As solution you don't need to store `playerLayer` property in you player class. Or you can create some decorator class what will manage both - player and his layer