# Compare dates from given array and two date ranges swift

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, xcode6, compare, nsdate

Hi I have a problem scenario with date comparison with given date range the scenario is as follows:

I have an array containing data:

```
var filter1Date = [String]()

filter1Date[Wed, 06 May 2015 03:44:19 GMT, Wed, 06 May 2015 03:36:27 GMT, Wed, 06 May 2015 02:56:51 GMT, Wed, 06 May 2015 01:54:25 GMT, Tue, 05 May 2015 19:17:18 GMT, Wed, 06 May 2015 02:57:59 GMT, Wed, 06 May 2015 02:07:38 GMT, Wed, 06 May 2015 01:53:14 GMT, Tue, 05 May 2015 14:30:10 GMT, Tue, 05 May 2015 14:04:34 GMT]
```

Now I have two dates which gives **from** and **to** two dates 
example:

```
var fromDate = "dd-MM-yyyy"
var toDate = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

now I want to compare array of **filter1Date** variable with range **fromDate** and **toDate** variable

from this I have to get data from **filter1Date** which ranges in between these dates can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Do you already have the filter1Date saved as NSDates?

Comment: filter1Date is of type [string]()

Comment: Do you know how to convert it to [NSDate]() ? Or do you need help with that too? Also fromDate and toDate must also be NSDate()

Comment: yes i want to convert.

Comment: Okay, i'll help you, but you'll need to do something by yourself to. Stackoverflow isn't a page where you get everything on a golden plate. Try to convert all the strings to a NSDate() type. Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/converting-a-string-to-an-nsdate

Comment: you shared link for objective-c how ever i am doing in swift

Comment: Its the same principe and the same methods are used. Do you understand Objective-C code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77862/discussion-between-nagarjun-and-dejan-skledar).

Comment: Have you managed to convert the strings to NSDates ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare two `NSDates` you can use `NSDate.compare()` method. I wrote an extension for the NSDate to handle this:

```
extension NSDate
{
    func isInRange(from: NSDate, to:NSDate) -> Bool
    {
        if(self.compare(from) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending || self.compare(from) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame)
        {
            if(self.compare(to) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending || self.compare(to) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame)
            {
                // date is in range
                return true
            }
        }
        // date is not in range
        return false
    }
}
```

## You can then use it like this:

```
var dates:[NSDate] = ... // your dates array

var startDate:NSDate // your start range date
var endDate:NSDate // your end range date

for date in dates
{
   if(date.isInRange(startDate, to: endDate))
   {
      //date is in range, do something
   }
   else
   {
      //date is not in range
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I'd just add that perhaps it would be better to use NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(date:toDate:ToUnitGranularity) so you can expand on the functionality and compare just the dates (if necessary).