# How to convert NSString to a date formattted string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have string with value `01012016` which i want to show to user like `01-01-2016`. For this, i am using the below code

```
-(NSString *)dateToFormatedDate:(NSString *)dateStr {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

    NSLog(@"date is %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

But this method is always returning nil. I have tried on simulator and device both.
I am not able to figure it out what i did wrong here

Comment: Have you tried `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy"];` when reading the string and then `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];` when writing it?

Comment: Check out http://nsdateformatter.com for examples of date formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of your `NSDateFormatter` does not match the string you're trying to pass it. Take a look at this related question...

[Converting a string to an NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/converting-a-string-to-an-nsdate)

What you want to do is set the `NSDateFormatter` to match the string, then once you've created an `NSDate` object from the string, change the `NSDateFormatter` to your desired output format. Something like this...

```
-(NSString *)dateToFormatedDate:(NSString *)dateStr {

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

  NSLog(@"date is %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
  return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```